# How do I select a range of keys from tarantool, like with SELECT BETWEEN in SQL?

Tags: tarantool

Since this is on of the most common questions in https://t.me/tarantool and https://t.me/tarantoolru, I post the answer here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```lua
space:pairs(from, 'GE'):
   take_while(function(x) return x.field <= to end)
   -- :totable() or use the result in the for-loop
```

For multipart keys see https://stackoverflow.com/a/57766656/1135874

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using Lua as well as SQL.

1) Use a stored procedure in Lua, like this one:

```
function select_between(space_name, index_name, field_name, from, to)
    local obj = index_name == nil and box.space[space_name] or box.space[space_name].index[index_name]

    local result = {}
    for _, tuple in obj:pairs(from, {iterator = 'GE'}) do
        if (tuple[field_name] <= to) then
            table.insert(result, tuple)
        else
            break
        end
    end
    return result
end


select_between('test', nil, 'id', 1, 3)
```

2) Starting with Tarantool 2.0, you can use SQL (provided that you have space format):

```
box.execute('select * from "test" where "id" between 1 and 3;')
```